# Using Express and MongoDB - How do I log out a User?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, jwt

I was following a tutorial at [Authentication in NodeJS With Express and Mongo - CodeLab #1](https://dev.to/dipakkr/implementing-authentication-in-nodejs-with-express-and-jwt-codelab-1-j5i)

I got everything to work perfectly, but the tutorial does not address how to log out a user.

From what I can tell, the session is being saved on Mongoose Atlas, which is the database I am using. When I log a user in with Postman, I get a token back. But I am not sure how to configure the /logout route.

Here is my code:

```
//routes/user.js
const express = require("express");
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");

const User = require("../models/User");

/**
 * @method - POST
 * @param - /signup
 * @description - User SignUp
 */

//Signup
router.post(
  "/signup",
  [
    check("username", "Please Enter a Valid Username")
      .not()
      .isEmpty(),
    check("email", "Please enter a valid email").isEmail(),
    check("password", "Please enter a valid password").isLength({
      min: 6
    })
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: errors.array()
      });
    }

    const {
      username,
      email,
      password
    } = req.body;
    try {
      let user = await User.findOne({
        email
      });
      if (user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          msg: "User Already Exists"
        });
      }

      user = new User({
        username,
        email,
        password
      });

      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

      await user.save();

      const payload = {
        user: {
          id: user.id
        }
      };

      jwt.sign(
        payload,
        "randomString", {
        expiresIn: 10000
      },
        (err, token) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.status(200).json({
            token
          });
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      res.status(500).send("Error in Saving");
    }
  }
);

// Login
router.post(
  "/login",
  [
    check("email", "Please enter a valid email").isEmail(),
    check("password", "Please enter a valid password").isLength({
      min: 6
    })
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: errors.array()
      });
    }

    const { email, password } = req.body;
    try {
      let user = await User.findOne({
        email
      });
      if (!user)
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: "User Not Exist"
        });

      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (!isMatch)
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: "Incorrect Password !"
        });

      const payload = {
        user: {
          id: user.id
        }
      };

      jwt.sign(
        payload,
        "randomString",
        {
          expiresIn: 3600
        },
        (err, token) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.status(200).json({
            token
          });
        }
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Server Error"
      });
    }
  }
);

// router.route("/logout").get(function (req, res, next) {
//   if (expire(req.headers)) {
//     delete req.user;
//     return res.status(200).json({
//       "message": "User has been successfully logged out"
//     });
//   } else {
//     return next(new UnauthorizedAccessError("401"));
//   }
// });

router.get("/me", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // request.user is getting fetched from Middleware after token authentication
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
    res.json(user);
  } catch (e) {
    res.send({ message: "Error in Fetching user" });
  }


});

router.get('/logout', isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  console.log('User Id', req.user._id);
  User.findByIdAndRemove(req.user._id, function (err) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    res.json({ message: 'User Deleted!' });
  })
});


module.exports = router;

function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  console.log("req: " + JSON.stringify(req.headers.authorization));
  // if (!(req.headers && req.headers.authorization)) {
  //   return res.status(400).send({ message: 'You did not provide a JSON web token in the authorization header' });
  //}
};
```

```
///middleware/auth.js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header("token");
  if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ message: "Auth Error" });

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "randomString");
    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).send({ message: "Invalid Token" });
  }
};
```

```
///models/User.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
});

// export model user with UserSchema
module.exports = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

So my question is, how can I implement a /logout route so that if the user clicks the logout button and invokes that route, their token is destroyed. I am only asking about the back-end part. I can handle using axios.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see, you are not saving any session data or storing tokens anywhere - which is great. You are simply appending the token to your headers in requests to the API.

So the only thing you can do is possibly expire the token in the `/logout route`
and then ensure you delete the token on the client - could be localStorage, sessionStorage etc - your client code needs to kill the token so it cannot be included again.

Side note:

1. You are not extending the token lifetime anywhere, so even if the user keeps interacting on the website, the token expiration is not being updated. You will need to manually refresh the token/generate a new token to have a sliding expiration.
2. I would suggest you save the token in cookies rather. Set the cookie to HttpOnly, Secure, and specify the domain. This is **far more secure** and will allow you to also expire the cookie from the API. If any scripts you include get compromised, they can access all your users’ tokens easily.

Example:

```
import {serialize} from 'cookie';
import jsend from 'jsend';

...
const token = jwt.sign(
    {
        id: validationResult.value.id // whatever you want to add to the token, here it is the id of a user
    },
    privateKeyBuffer,
    {
        expiresIn: process.env.token_ttl,
        algorithm: 'RS256'
    });

const cookieOptions = {
    httpOnly: true,
    path: '/',
    maxAge: process.env.token_ttl,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.token_ttl),
    sameSite: process.env.cookie_samesite, // strict
    domain: process.env.cookie_domain, // your domain
    secure: process.env.cookie_secure // true
};

const tokenCookie = await serialize('token', token, cookieOptions);

res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [tokenCookie]);

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.status(200).json(jsend.success(true));
```

Then in logout:

```
    // grab from req.cookies.token and validate
    const token = await extractToken(req);

    // you can take action if it's invalid, but not really important
    if(!token) {
       ...
    }

    // this is how we expire it - the options here must match the options you created with!
    const cookieOptions = {
        httpOnly: true,
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 0,
        expires: 0,
        sameSite: process.env.cookie_samesite, // strict
        domain: process.env.cookie_domain, // your domain
        secure: process.env.cookie_secure // true
    };

    // set to empty 
    const tokenCookie = await serialize('token', '', cookieOptions);

    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [tokenCookie]);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.status(200).json(jsend.success(true));
```

Comment: ok. It looks like I have a few more things to learn here. So I know how to use local storage. I still need to figure out how to expire the token, which is what I cannot seem to figure out. I guess from my React front end, I would get the token from the response and then save it to local storage. Then I have to figure out how to update the expiration date in local storage.  Can you tell me how to expire the token in the logout route?

Comment: Please remember to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it has solved your issue and answered your question.

Comment: Thank you Samuel. I will give this a shot. I appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0):

As you have used JWT the backend will always check 2 things
 1. Proper token
 2. If time is over for that particular (You should handle this one)

For 2nd point, if the user time is up than from frontend you may delete the token if you have stored the token in localstorage.

For logout when user clicks on logout just delete jwt from localstorage and redirect to login or other page

Comment: I am not storing the token anywhere. Maybe that is the problem. I assumed that the token was stored by Mongoose from within the /login route. Now that I look more closely at that code, it looks like the token is just generated, but I still need to store it. Do I have that right?

Comment: Where does the /me route get it's information? The /me route returns the logged in user based on the token.

Comment: @David.Warwick you can keep the token in req.header.authorization and get info of user by decrypting the token of the user (You may keep info of user in token)

Answer (score 0):

Its a Simple Solution

```
const Logout = async (req, res, next) => {
res.cookie('cookie', '', {
    expireIn: new Date(Date.now())
})
return res.status(200).json({ message: 'User Logout Successfully' })
```

}

Very Simple Way to Logout a User